# Auto Order Confirmation Not Sending - 1.9.2.2 Hostgator

Tags: magento-1.9

I recently upgraded my Magento installation to 1.9.2.2 and Customers are not getting an auto notification upon placing an order all of the sudden. I Read up on cron for these emails. I believe everything is set up correctly - Is there some configuration that I am missing? Any help will be appreciated.
[image: Cron setup]

I installed AOE Scheduler to test and verify cron - that seems to be working fine.

The only way I can get an email to the customer is by hitting the send email on the order - I WANT THIS TO BE AUTOMATED - USED TO BE:
[image]

I check my settings in Configuration - they seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

With Magento 1.9.1 the emails are not being sent directly during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob - please ensure this has been set up and is running correctly.

The extension AOE_Scheduler can help you in confirming that your Magento cronjob has been configured correctly and is running.

**EDIT**

install this module https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html configure it with Google app or gmail and make sure that in settings of module system->configuration->SMTP pro->Queue Usage is Never and i believe that it works !

Comment: I have set it up - AOE_Scheduler appears to be working and cron status. Still any idea why I might not be able to receive the mails?

Comment: Look my answer now